# How index_id for non-clustered index is calculated in MSSQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

According to the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-partition-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 for non clustered index index_id has a value greater than one. But I am unable to find a reference to how the value for index_id column is calculated in table sys.dm_db_partition_stats in the case of non clustered index ?

Comment: Are you after [sys.dm_db_partition_stats (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-partition-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? (Which uses the same logic for `index_id`.)

Comment: `index_id` corresponds to the `index_id` in `sys.indexes`. Nothing should be assumed about this number if it's not 0 or 1; it's just a unique value.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at the same documentation.

Comment: Thanks your comment does address my question. Can you please post it as an answer? So that I can accept it as a solution.